# Windowing Data into Rows in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm preparing a dataset to develop a supervised model to predict a value given the 5 previous values before it. For example given the sample data below, I would predict the 6th column given columns 1:5, or the 8th column given columns 3:7.

```
id    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16 ...
a    150 110 130  80 136 150 190 110 150 110 130 136 100 150 190 110
b    100 100 130 100 136 100 160 230 122 130  15 200 100 100 136 100
c    130 122 140 140 122 130  15 200 100 100 130 100 136 100 160 230
```

To that end, I want to reorganize the sample data above into rows of 6 columns, taking every slice/window of 6 values possible (e.g. 1:6, 2:7, 3:8). How can I do that? Is it possible in PySpark/SQL? Example of output below, index just for clarification:

```
           1   2   3   4   5   6   
a[1:6]    150 110 130  80 136 150 
a[2:7]    110 130  80 136 150 190
a[3:8]    130  80 136 150 190 110
...
c[1:6]    130 122 140 140 122 130
c[2:7]    122 140 140 122 130  15
...
c[10:16]  130 100 136 100 160 230
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your columns into an *array of arrays* or *array of structs* and then explode, for example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, explode, array, col

# all columns except the first
cols = df.columns[1:]

# size of the splits
N = 6
```

**Use array of arrays:**

```
df_new = df.withColumn('dta', explode(array(*[ array(*cols[i:i+N]) for i in range(len(cols)-N+1) ]))) \
    .select('id', *[ col('dta')[i].alias(str(i+1)) for i in range(N) ])
df_new.show()
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| id|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|150|110|130| 80|136|150|
|  a|110|130| 80|136|150|190|
|  a|130| 80|136|150|190|110|
|  a| 80|136|150|190|110|150|
|  a|136|150|190|110|150|110|
|  a|150|190|110|150|110|130|
|  a|190|110|150|110|130|136|
|  a|110|150|110|130|136|100|
|  a|150|110|130|136|100|150|
|  a|110|130|136|100|150|190|
|  a|130|136|100|150|190|110|
|  b|100|100|130|100|136|100|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

**Use array of structs (spark 2.4+):**

```
df_new = df.withColumn('dta', array(*cols)) \
    .selectExpr("id", f"""
      inline(transform(sequence(0,{len(cols)-N}), i -> ({','.join(f'dta[i+{j}] as `{j+1}`' for j in range(N))})))
    """)
```

the code inside above f-string is the same as the following for N=6:

```
inline(transform(sequence(0,10), i -> struct(dta[i] as `1`, dta[i+1] as `2`, dta[i+2] as `3`, dta[i+3] as `4`, dta[i+4] as `5`, dta[i+5] as `6`)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use this code (and modify it to get what you need):

```
partitions = []
for row in df.rdd.toLocalIterator():
    row_list = list(row)
    num_elements = 6

    for i in range(0, len(row_list) - num_elements):
        partition = row[i : i+num_elements]
        partitions.append(partition)

output_df = spark.createDataFrame(partitions)
```